# how to initialize multiple objects with unique names

Tags: ios, xcode, object, namespaces, rename

I'm sure this is a very basic procedure, so excuse this newbie question.

How would I initialize several objects, with the same code, but each with a unique name? I can make a string to represent theName, but how would I apply that as the actual objects name? Can I rename the object?

BTW the purpose is so that I can perform operations on each object referring to them by name, at a later time... I think that unique names would be a solution to this issue...

```
    NSString *theName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"textView%d",tvNum];

    tvNum ++;

    UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width /2, self.view.bounds.size.height /2, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:myTextView];
    NSString *theText = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"string"];
    [myTextView setText:theText];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add tags to your controller later to refer it.

```
myTextView.tag = somePreCalculatedTagValue;
```

and later by matching that tag value with controller you can do what you want

```
if(myTextView.tag == kTagForFirstTextView)
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to create an array of objects. You can use a for loop to set them up:

```
NSMutableArray *objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:NUM_OF_OBJECTS];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_OBJECTS; i++) {
    UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width /2, self.view.bounds.size.height /2, 100, 100)];
    [myTextView setText:@"string"];
    [objectArray addObject:myTextView];
    [self.view addSubview:myTextView];
}
```

and later refer to them later by their index:

```
UITextView *thirdTextView = [objectArray objectAtIndex:2];
thirdTextView.text = @"Foobar";
```

or just:

```
[objectArray objectAtIndex:2].text = @"Foobar";
```